# How to add has_one_attached depending on a configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-activestorage

I have a gem which I want to generate a qrcode if config is enabled with active_storage

```
app/config/initializers/cryptocoin_payable.rb

CryptocoinPayable.configure do |config|
  config.qrcode = :active_storage
end
```

```
class CryptocoinPayable::CoinPayment < ActiveRecord::Base

if CryptoCoinPayable::Configuration.qrcode == :active_storage
 has_one_attached :qrcode
end

end
```

It didnt work because

```
CryptoCoinPayable::Configuration is nil
```

I tried to put it after initialization

```
module CryptocoinPayable
end

if defined?(Rails)
  module CryptocoinPayable
    class Railtie < Rails::Railtie

      initializer 'cryptocoin_payable.active_storage' do
        ActiveSupport.on_load(:after_initialize) do
          require 'cryptocoin_payable/coin_payment'
          if (CryptocoinPayable.configuration == :qrcode)
            CryptocoinPayable::CoinPayment.has_one_attached(:qrcode)
           end
        end

      end

      rake_tasks do
        path = File.expand_path(__dir__)
        Dir.glob("#{path}/tasks/**/*.rake").each { |f| load f }
      end
    end
  end
end

require 'cryptocoin_payable/config'
require 'cryptocoin_payable/errors'
require 'cryptocoin_payable/version'
require 'cryptocoin_payable/adapters'
```

But it doesnt work "qrcode" is undefined method

How can I make `has_*one_*attached` depending on a config ??

Here is the respo: https://github.com/sbounmy/cryptocoin_payable

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is :

Make sure we initialize correctly `after` active_storage are reflected.
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9064735ec5cd3c679f8ffabc42532dd85223af58/activestorage/lib/active_storage/engine.rb#L171 (if you try after attached it will raise an unsupported Macro error)

```
      initializer 'cryptocoin_payable.active_storage', after: 'active_storage.reflection' do
    require 'cryptocoin_payable/coin_payment'
    config.after_initialize do
      if CryptocoinPayable.configuration.qrcode?
        CryptocoinPayable::CoinPayment.has_one_attached(:qrcode)
      end
    end
  end
```

Also make sure rspec does pick up the railtie in my case I had to require 'rails' in my spec_helper before the cryptocoin_payable (defined?(Rails))